# Хранение таблички в файле .TXT

Tags: php, кэширование

В базе у меня табличка примерно такого содержимого

- заголовок
- описание
- новость
- и т.д.

Как вот такие данные сохранить в файле txt, чтобы не создавать число файлов равное количеству столбцов в табличке?

Answer (score 6):

Можно в CSV-формате, можно в JSON-е, можно PHP-массив пропускать через функцию serialize()

Comment: Еще можно в xml.

Comment: Да, можно в xml. Спецом не стал про него писать. Для кеширования - не лучший вариант. Слишком много лишнего. У него обычно другая область применения.

Comment: а вот например из базы инфа достается в виде обьекта я могу ее пихнуть (обьект) в функцию serialize() ?
она с масивами работает?
и какой ее принцип действия, что собственно функция делает с данными?

Comment: @gjhgfddjhgjhg, `serialize()` работает и с массивами и с объектами.

Answer (score 3):

Все переменные поместите в одну переменную и запишите в файл.

```
$str = $title . "|" . $description . "|" . $news . "|" ...;
```

Далее открываете файл при помощи: [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php) в режиме `a+b`, подробнее смотрите справку по работе с этой функцией.

Comment: А если, например, в поле "заголовок" встретится символ `|` , как будешь разбирать?

Comment: Необходимо предварительно использовать [htmlspecialchars()][1]

[1]: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: А чем эта функция поможет? Она не экранирует символ `|`

Comment: А зачем его экранировать? Он будет представлен как html-сущность: &#124;, но когда будет выведен в окно браузера, то примет свой стандартный вид - |.

Смотрите на мой пример как на пример, а не финальную часть кода. Да и потом, что мешает изменить разделитель? Скажем, вместо - |, использовать - |||, или ещё какую-нибудь комбинацию символов.

Comment: Я все это к тому, что не нужно на ровном месте изобретать велосипеды.

Есть масса проработанных форматов. И, более того, в PHP есть все необходимое чтобы с этими форматами работать.

Comment: Согласен есть. На мой взгляд, вариант с CSV самый лучший в данной ситуации. Есть одно маленькое но. @gjhgfddjhgjhg спросил как ему это сделать с использованием txt-файла.

Comment: Суть вопроса в том, чтобы кешировать выборки из БД в файлах. Какая разница с какими расширениями эти файлы будут? И, что мешает записать в txt сериализованный массив или json?

И, CSV, не самый лучший вариант.